# Any downsides to using `from __future__ import annotations` everywhere?

Tags: python, annotations, python-typing

From [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/), it seems like there should be slight performance gains, as it solves

> type hints are executed at module import time, which is not computationally free.

So...could/should I include `from __future__ import annotations` in every file in my package, or are there any reasons it should be excluded from some files?

Answer (score 12):

TLDR: Some things will not work with `from __future__ import annotations`. Since a future version of Python will make postponed evaluation mandatory, code striving for forward compatibility should not rely on prompt evaluation in the first place.

---

Since `from __future__ import annotations` avoids the evaluation of type hints, anything that depends on evaluated type hints must [explicitly evaluate type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints). This is usually not possible outside of top-level module or class scopes, unless `locals` are explicitly handled.

For example, `functools.singledispatch` cannot use type hints inside functions if annotation evaluation is postponed:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Type
from functools import singledispatch

def non_global_sdp(local_type: Type):
    @singledispatch
    def default(arg): print("default")

    @default.register
    def case_a(arg: local_type): print("case_a")

    return default

cases = non_global_sdp(int)  # NameError: name 'local_type' is not defined
```

---

[The exact semantics of postponed evaluation of annotations and mandatory introduction version are still undecided.](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/VIZEBX5EYMSYIJNDBF6DMUMZOCWHARSO/) Of the current proposals the features of `from __future__ import annotations` are the most restrictive; any code that must work with future versions of Python should use `from __future__ import annotations` to avoid hidden dependencies on prompt evaluation.

> #### [`__future__` — Future statement definitions (Python 3.11)](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/__future__.html)
>
> [1] `from __future__ import annotations` was previously scheduled to become mandatory in Python 3.10, but the Python Steering Council twice decided to delay the change ([announcement for Python 3.10](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/CLVXXPQ2T2LQ5MP2Y53VVQFCXYWQJHKZ/); [announcement for Python 3.11](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/VIZEBX5EYMSYIJNDBF6DMUMZOCWHARSO/)). No final decision has been made yet. See also PEP 563 and PEP 649.

Comment: Maybe answer could be bit more explicit here: Some things will not work with from `__future__ import annotations`.

Comment: Your answer is unclear on whether `from __future__ import annotations` is good or bad. It is a good default, right? What does "code striving for forward compatibility should not rely on prompt evaluation in the first place" mean in practice?

Comment: @MarcosPereira "... is good or bad." That wasn't the question and is *much* more complex. "What does "…" mean in practice?" It means what is said in the end of the answer: "any code that must work with future versions of Python should use `from __future__ import annotations` to avoid hidden dependencies on prompt evaluation.".